# Import files in specified directory into separate pandas dataframes (and name them correspondingly)

Tags: python, windows, pandas

There are a lots of .csv files in a folder organized in sub-directoires under Win-server. They have different structure/size/number in each dir. Need to pick out all of them into ***different*** dataframes, name them correspondingly and jsonize each dataframe:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

singlefile = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob("C:\data\*.csv")]

#this will read them all into the same DataFrame
df = pd.concat(singlefile, axis=0)
...
#and finally dump it into predefined singlefile.json
df.to_json("C:\data\singlefile.json")
```

How do I modify this in order to parse them into different dataframes and then dump into different jsons?

1. Pick pick out all filesnames in the directory until !eof();
2. Loop over list of files to import to DF and assign unique names to them; - not to overwrite data in the same df;
3. Export each into separate jsons;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you will need to retain the data in memory or just need the JSON files I would suggest these approaches:

**If you only need the JSON files: Do everything sequentially (overwrite the DataFrame after it has been written to JSON)**

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

filenames = glob.glob("C:\data\*.csv")

for idx, fname in enumerate(filenames):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    out_fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fname))[0]
    ...
    # and finally dump it into predefined singlefile.json
    df.to_json("C:\data\df_{}.json".format(out_fname))
```

**If you need to retain all DataFrames in memory: Work with a dictionary**

```
import glob
import pandas as pd


filenames = glob.glob("C:\data\*.csv")

df_dict = {}

for idx, fname in enumerate(filenames):
    df_dict[fname] = pd.read_csv(fname)
    out_fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fname))[0]
    ...
    #and finally dump it into predefined singlefile.json
    df_dict[fname].to_json("C:\data\df_{}.json".format(out_fname))
```

Now you can access each DataFrame by its file name as a key.
Now the JSON have the same name as the CSV from which they are derived. E.g. if the if the csv is called "data_foo.csv", the JSON will be called "data_foo.json".

Comment: thank you @bexi - looks like correct answer, but the sequential one has some syntax err on line 4: `for idx, fname in filenames:` - "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I forgot the enumerate around filenames. I edited the answer.

Comment: yeh, thats because of index `idx` - can you give a hint how do I add any suffixes/prefixes/regex to that name? is there any easy way to parse original name of the .csv and name .json accordingly?

Comment: you don't even need regex for that :). I edited the answer again, now the JSON filnames are derived from the original CSV filename

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

singlefile is your list of pandas dataframes

```
[df.to_json("json_file_{}".format(i)) for i,df in enumerate(singlefile)]
```